# Continuity of a Piece-Wise function

Tags: real-analysis, limits, proof-verification

I am trying to show that 
$$f(x) = \begin{cases} \dfrac{\sin(x)}{x} \space\ , \space\ x \neq 0 \\ 1 \hspace{.3cm} , \hspace{1cm} x = 0 \end{cases}$$
is continuous without using L'Hopitals Rule (or derivatives in general).

My attempt:

Using the inequality:
$$0 < \sin(x) < x < \tan(x) \hspace{1cm} \forall x \in (0, \frac{\pi}{2})$$ 
and dividing through by $x$ we have that:
$$0 < \frac{\sin(x)}{x} < 1$$
Then, we manipulate the initial inequality:
$$0 < \sin(x)\cos(x) < x\cos(x) < \sin(x)$$
$$0 < \frac{\sin(x)\cos(x)}{x} < \cos(x) < \frac{\sin(x)}{x}$$
Combining these two pieces we have that:
$$\cos(x) < \frac{\sin(x)}{x} < 1$$
So by squeeze theorem, we have that 
$$\lim_{x\to0} \frac{\sin(x)}{x} = 1$$
since $\displaystyle\lim_{x\to0} \cos(x) = 1$.

Comment: If you assume one can apply
$
\lim_{x\to0}\frac{\sin x}{x}=1
$
then the proof is one line.

Comment: @Jack, how to evaluate that limit without using L'Hopitals rule as stipulated? Or were you suggesting that the restrictions are too severe?

Comment: Start with $0 < |\sin(x)| < |x| < |\tan(x)| \enspace \forall x \in (-\frac{\pi}{2}, \frac{\pi}{2})$ because you need $\lim_{x\to 0^-} =\lim_{x\to 0^+}$ . - Your way of calculation is o.k. .

Comment: Someone should speak to the continuity laws. I think that a proof of continuity should satisfy all three, where as this proof merely demonstrates that the limit is 1 which matches the function. So if its about proof, proving more formally is a good way to go.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you assume one can apply
$$
\lim_{x\to0}\frac{\sin x}{x}=1\tag{1}
$$
then the proof is of one line. Otherwise, you are essentially asking for a proof of (1), which would depend on how you *define* the function $f(x)=\sin x$.

---

Using L'Hospital to prove (1) would be circular in a calculus textbook (by Stewart for instance), because (1) is used to calculate the derivative (by definition) of $f$ .

---

Here is a calculus 101 proof from Stewart:

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: The statement on line 1, which is based on a geometric picture of areas of triangles and a circle sector, is usually the typical way to prove this standard limit. Not only Stewart (do you happen to know what page?), but I have seen other calculus textbooks use L'Hospital's Rule to "prove" the limit, which is indeed a form of circular reasoning.

Comment: It is in the section "derivatives of trigonometric functions" in Stewart.

Comment: The edit makes sense +1. Stewart indeed uses the geometric argument for the limit (p146)

Answer (score 0):

Write sinx in the expanded series form and divide it throughout by x. You can then apply limit directly by substituting x=0 and you will get the limit 1 which is equal to the function value and hence the function is continuous at x=0.